What's the most computationally efficient implementation of Kalman Filter
I know there are many formulations of the Kalman Filter. A few I can name are:

Classical Covariance Form
Informational Filter Form
Square-Root Form or Factor Form

But somehow it's hard for me to find a summary of their pros and cons from the computational standpoint. I want to find the computationally cheapest solution.
In my use case, my state transition matrix is the identity (the $F$ matrix in wikipedia) and the state transition noise covariance $Q$ matrix has a nice principal component structural (I can just take the first dozens of eigenvalues to compress the covariance matrix).  My observation vector size is usually at least 1/3, sometimes more than the state vector. My $R$ (observation noise) is diagonal. We can assume $R,Q$ are constant for all practical purposes
But I'd like to hear more about this computation complexity topic in general.

Can one assume $\boldsymbol{R}$ and $\boldsymbol{Q}$ are constant for your case?

@Royi  Not 100% but once they change, they are usually constant for a long period of time.  So for all practical purposes, yes we can assume they are contant.
